# PI Approximation: Why is my declarative version slower?

Tags: clojure

I'm approximating PI using the series:

[image: PI Sereies]

The function for the series then looks like this:

```
(defn- pi-series [k]
  (/ (if (even? (inc k)) 1 -1)
     (dec (* 2 k))))
```

And then my series generator looks like *:

```
(defn pi [n]
  (* 4
    (loop [k 1
           acc 0]
      (if (= k (inc n))
        acc
        (recur (inc k) 
               (+ acc (double (pi-series k))))))))
```

Running `pi` with the value `999,999` produces the following:

```
(time (pi 999999))
;;=> "Elapsed time: 497.686 msecs"
;;=> 3.1415936535907734
```

That looks great, but I realize `pi` could be written more declarative. Here's what I ended up with:

```
(defn pi-fn [n]
  (* 4 (reduce + 
               (map #(double (pi-series %)) 
                    (range 1 (inc n))))))
```

Which resulted in the following:

```
(time (pi-fn 999999))
;;=> "Elapsed time: 4431.626 msecs"
;;=> 3.1415936535907734
```

NOTE: The declarative version took around 4-seconds longer. Why?

Why is the declarative version so much slower? How can I update the declarative version to make it as fast as the imperative version?

---

- I'm casting the result of pi-series to a double, because using clojure's ratio types performed a lot slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the way, you can express an alternating finite sum as a difference of two sums, eliminating the need to adjust each term for sign individually. For example,

```
(defn alt-sum [f n]
  (- (apply + (map f (range 1 (inc n) 2)))
     (apply + (map f (range 2 (inc n) 2)))))

(time (* 4 (alt-sum #(/ 1.0 (dec (+ % %))) 999999)))
; "Elapsed time: 195.244047 msecs"
;= 3.141593653590707
```

On my laptop `pi` runs at 2500 msec. However,  `pi` and  `pi-fn` (either version) run at approx. the same rate (10x slower than `alt-sum`). More often than not, `pi-fn` is  *faster* than `pi`. Are you sure you didn't accidentally insert an extra 9 before the second timing? Contra Juan, I do not think you're iterating over the sequence more than once, since the terms are generated lazily.

```
scratch.core> (time (pi 999999))
"Elapsed time: 2682.86669 msecs"
3.1415936535907734
scratch.core> (time (pi-fn 999999))
"Elapsed time: 2082.071798 msecs"
3.1415936535907734
scratch.core> (time (pi-fn-juan 999999))
"Elapsed time: 1934.976217 msecs"
3.1415936535907734
scratch.core> (time (* 4 (alt-sum #(/ 1.0 (dec (+ % %))) 999999)))
"Elapsed time: 199.998438 msecs"
3.141593653590707
```

Comment: @manualcranck You are absolutely right, the original `pi-fn` does run in approximately the same time as the `pi`. My "explanation" was bogus :). Is there a way to delete an accepted answer?